# Communication between two fragment from different activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have two activities in my app. In `MainActivity` I am loading 2 fragments `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`. From `Fragment1` i am jumping to `Fragment2` and from `Fragment2` I am jumping to `Activity2` which contains `Fragment2_1` From `Fragment 2_1` I want to jump back to `Fragment2` in `MainActivity` but I am getting an error when I try to do this.

I want to know is it possible to jump from 1 activity fragment to another activity fragment?

My code is:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment1=new Fragment1();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer,fragment1,"MainActivity");
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }
}
```

Fragment1.java:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
        Button buttonfrag1=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonfrag1);
        buttonfrag1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer,fragment2,"Fragment1");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Fragment2.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {


    public Fragment2() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false);
        Button buttonfrag2=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonfrag2);
        buttonfrag2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        return view;

    }

}
```

Activity2.java

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment2_1 fragment2_1=new Fragment2_1();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag2_1,fragment2_1,"Activity2");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }
}
```

Fragment2_1.java

```
public class Fragment2_1 extends Fragment {


    public Fragment2_1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2_1, container, false);
        Button buttonfrag2_1=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonfrag2_1);
        buttonfrag2_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment2 fragment2=new Fragment2();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer,fragment2,"frag2_1");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

All code works fine but when I want to move from Fragment2_1 to Fragment1 my app crashes with an exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0059 (saleskit.orbitsys.com.fragmentdemo:id/mainContainer) for fragment Fragment2{29eb9c90 #1 id=0x7f0b0059 frag2_1}
```

Comment: Did you get your answer? Check my answer below. @champadorid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: in Fragment2_1

```
 buttonfrag2_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("frag", "fragment2");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Now in Mainactivity `onResume()` load your desired fragment in `maincontainer`

in `MainActivity`

```
    @Override
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();

  Intent intent = getIntent();

if(intent.getExtras() != null)
{
 String frag = intent.getStringExtra("frag");
}


  switch(frag){

    case "fragment2":
       //here you can load Fragment2 to your activity as usual;
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainer, new Fragment2()).commit();
       break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for response but by your answer I am on Activity2 I want to move again Fragment2 when user click on button of Fragment2_1

Comment: add this `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag2_1,fragment2,"frag2_1");` on your `Fragment2_1` to go to `Fragement2`

Comment: the exception occurs as your are passing wrong id in fragment2_1  during transaction to fragment2

Comment: Did this sir , I know i can jump on Fragment2 by this. But now fragment 2 is loaded inside Activity2 container I want to load Fragment2 inside maincontainer.

Comment: Please can you help @rafsanahmad

Comment: App Crashes at starting .

Comment: nullPointerException

Comment: you have to get `putextra` values like :`String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");'

Comment: Getting same error sir ,                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: String frag = intent.getStringExtra("frag");
Here I am getting frag null.

Comment: Thanks sir. for all your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Fragment2_1` within your second activity you are trying to place `Fragment2` in the container `R.id.mainContainer`. Your code below :

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment2 fragment2=new Fragment2();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainContainer,fragment2,"frag2_1");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But since you are currently inside your second activity that container doesn't exist (it is part of your first activity). You need to either load your your `MainActivity` again or finish `Activity2` by calling `finish()`. If you do the later android will by itself take you back to your `MainActivity` and since you moved to `Activity2` from `Fragment2` android will also remember that and show you `Fragment2`.

Your Fragment2_1 should look like this:

```
public class Fragment2_1 extends Fragment {

    public Fragment2_1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2_1, container, false);
        Button buttonfrag2_1=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonfrag2_1);
        buttonfrag2_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               getActivity().finish();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

**OR**, If you just want to show `Fragment2` in your second activity you can do something like this :

```
public class Fragment2_1 extends Fragment {


    public Fragment2_1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2_1, container, false);
        Button buttonfrag2_1=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonfrag2_1);
        buttonfrag2_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Fragment2 fragment2=new Fragment2();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag2_1,fragment2,"frag2");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

**`R.id.frag2_1`** is the container where you need to replace the fragment.

Note that : You will still be in your second activity. Just the fragment will be replaced.

Comment: The problem is that sir . I can't finish the second activity .

Comment: @champadorid You can't or you don't want to ?